# grant access to a command only for certain arguments (chown for a path)

Tags: permissions, sudo, jenkins, sudoers

I have a script that require to change the owner recursively in a folder

there is my specific sudoers file:
/etc/sudoers.d/jenkins

```
jenkins ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/chmod, /bin/chown
```

and this is the command that jenkins need to execute:

```
chown -R apache:apache /var/www/vhosts/${HOST}/${PROJECT}
```

for security reasons, i need to restrict the sudo permissions only for chown with argument /var/www/vhosts/***

there are some regex in sudoers file to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use wildcards:

```
jenkins ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/chown -R apache:apache /var/www/vhosts/*
```

Though it's probably safer from a security perspective to write your own script so that you can validate arguments and ensure that only exactly the paths you want to affect are affected:

```
jenkins ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/my-custom-chown-script
```